# Why are there two LTE antennas?

Tags: rf, antenna, receiver, pcb-antenna, lte

I have a design with LTE CAT 4 and I wonder why two antennas are needed.  I searched around the web but am still kind of confused.  Below are my questions:

1. Is the second antenna used for Rx only?
2. Is LTE modem trying to select which antenna gives the best reception? Or the modem will combine LTE signals from two antenna?
3. If only main LTE antenna is used, what's the impact?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first thing to understand is that what you're asking is basically a content of a couple of university courses, so it's a bit difficult to give an in-depth explanation.

In short, you didn't give a link to modem, so we can't be precise, but there are some general statements that can be made:

1. Should be.
2. Modem will combine both antennas.
3. It's complicated!

In short, category 4 LTE is trying to do so-called spatial multiplexing. The idea is that the antennas will be sufficiently distant, so that (oversimplifying here) each antenna can send its own independent data stream. To do that, you need sufficient number of antennas (also called "layers") at both the transmitter and the receiver. If you disconnect one of the antennas on your modem, you've just completely lost a spatial stream.

Cat 4 devices have one uplink spatial stream and two downlink spatial streams. So, if you remove a spatial stream, then you're more or less down to category 1.

I'm also not sure if the modem will try to do anything smart when transmitting, such as trying out which antenna is better for transmission or not. If I remember correctly, in category 4, there shouldn't be any uplink beamforming or anything else that would require more than 1 transmit antenna, but it's been a while.

Comment: Why would it take "a couple of university courses" to give an idea why two antennas are needed? Noone is asking here for "in-depth" dissertations. Your 2-paragraph explanation seems sufficient for a reasonably educated reader to grasp the idea of processing of spatial correlations, and gives a direction where to look. If you could throw few numbers on relationship of RF wavelength relative to antenna placement and edit out the condescending remark about "university courses", you would get +1 from me.

Comment: @Ali Chen Well, I don't think I should do that. I don't actually find it condescending at all, it's just the way things are, especially since OP provided no information about his level of understanding. In my answer, I provided absolutely no explanation why exactly are the two antennas needed. I just said that they are because of spatial streams, basically appealing to my own authority. Real answer would be to go in-depth and talk about receiver architecture, the assumptions needed for independent spatial streams and so on.

Comment: @Ali Chen Furthermore, spatial sampling is a minefield of its own. I'm afraid, that if I do provide some basic information about it, it won't be enough to even start seriously digging into the field. I'll think about it a bit more. If you believe that a short and concise, but not "dumbed down" answer can be easily provided, I invite you to do so. I would most certainly up-vote it.

Comment: Andrej, you are an expert here, not me. If you can provide some basic keywords related to the concept of "spatial stream", it will be of great help. Or a reference to a plain layman-level publication will clear the complexity of the subject, like this one: http://download.ni.com/evaluation/rf/Introduction_to_LTE_Device_Testing.pdf

Comment: Thanks, Andrea, Ali.  I also found the answers as well.  Andrea, your first 2 answers are correct.  The third one is complicated.  Sorry for not specific enough.  In short, theoretically the impact is diversity path will increase the sensitivity by 3dB.  Two antennas required to meet the required specification as per 3GPP standard.

Comment: @jsmith0910 In that case, why don't you post that as an answer here and accept it? If you don't, the question is going to keep getting bumped up.

Answer (score 2):

It is because category 4 LTE devices support 2x2 MIMO on the downlink (base station to mobile).

So:

1. Using the two antennas simultaneously, is only for the downlink (receiving). But for transmitting, only one antenna would be used (could be either one of the two, depending on the device).
2. The modem will combine the signal received on the two antennas, depending on the LTE transmission mode used.
3. It's not clear what you mean. Category 4 LTE devices need to have 2 antennas. It is part of the requirements for Category 4. Otherwise, go for a lower category device, e.g., Category 1 or 2, and be prepared for lower performance, lower data rates, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The second antenna is the diversity antenna. It's designed to reduce errors due to the signal reflecting off various surfaces on it's way from the transmitter to the receiver which would arrive slightly out of phase with the main direct signal. Those high data rates are achieved with phase and amplitude modulation and reflected signals cause errors.
You can normally turn off the diversity antenna on an LTE modem. On a Quectel modem you use the following command:

AT+QCFG="diversity",0

Cat1.bis modems don't need a diversity antenna. These are used for IoT applications where designers never design in a second antenna.